KStreams KTbale left join is not working for all records
I am doing the table, table left join operation using the KStreams, the episodes records are coming for the particular show, these episodes records used to get enriched.
Even though the records exists in the KTable for show, episode records is not getting the enriched (join). This issue is happening for some episodes, but for other episodes (under different show), left join is working, data is getting enriched.
val enrichedEpisodeTable = episodeTable.leftJoin(
            showTable,
            { episode ->
                if (episode!!.relationships.shows.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    "NULL"
                } else {
                    episode.relationships.shows[0]
                }
            },
            EpisodeParentEnricher,
            Named.`as`(Names.ENRICHED_EPISODE_TABLE.name),
            materializes(Names.ENRICHED_EPISODE_STATE_STORE.name, config.combinedEntityValueSerde)
        )

The expected result should have the enriched data (left join) should work, as data exist in both the Ktables.

For a left join, if there is no correspondence of the left record in the KTable, you still get a result in the output stream.

Hard to say... What serialization format for the key are you using? The key-comparison happens on the serialized bytes, to a match is only found if both byte[] arrays are the same.
Also, did you verify that data to partitioned correctly, ie, the same on both sides?
